# Unable to connect to SVN repository from XCode 5

Tags: svn, repository, xcode5, svn-checkout

Can't able to connect to SVN repository from XCode 5

Tried with `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Account` > `Add Repository` (with bottom + button) and add svn path + username + password.

I tried with terminal as well and its working fine and checkout the project on server. 
But when i tried with Xcode(GUI) even not able to connect svn and getting below error message.

```
ERROR MSG: "svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://host/svn/test'"
```

Comment: Hello,Did u solved this error?

Comment: Have checked out with xCode4 and then use Xcode5. it will work fine for me. Actually I have installed two Xcode(4 & 5) in my mac.